# How to create dynamic url in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, react-router-dom

```
const category = { 
  q="",   
  mealtype="breakfast",  
  cuisinetype="American",   
  dishType="Soup" 
}  

const base = `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=${query}=&app_id=${app_id}&app_key=${app_key}`;
```

User can select any category ex `mealtype`, `cuisinetype`, `dishType`, or combination of them. I am looking for a way to construct url based on selected input.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive code example, it's unclear what isn't working in creating any URL. See [mcve]. From some example input what is the expected output?

Comment: so if a `category` property is not null or empty, it should be added to url?

Comment: @Apostolos Don't change the meaning of the code OP provided; code with possibly invalid syntax, typos, etc, is perfectly reviewable.

Answer (score 0):

This function generates url string out of input object, but drops keys with empty values:

```js
const category = { 
  q: "",   
  mealtype: "breakfast",  
  cuisinetype: "American",   
  dishType: "Soup" 
}


const obj2url = (params) =>
  Object.entries(params).reduce((prev, [key, value]) => value ? prev + `&${key}=${value}` : prev, '')

const url = "https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public" + obj2url(category)

console.log(url)
```